# How to convert string to time string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

How can I convert the following

string Time = "2324";
string Time = "1024";

In the first case the converted value should be another string "11:24 PM" .
The second case should be "10:24 AM".

I tried Date.ParseExact(Time,"hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
That solves it when the time is less than 12:00PM. But when it is "2324", I get 23:24 PM when I actually need 11:24 PM

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` using the format `"HHmm"`

Comment: Please [edit] question to show research you already did on the topic. This would make question to look much better as all sort of parse/format DateTime values questions are asked many times. Obviously you've looked at many and none helped - so adding all that research to the question will help to give you answer that you have not tried and rejected already, saving you from writing multitude of "why do you think I have not tried that" remarks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Method expects time to be always 4 characters

```
    static string ParseTime(string time)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(time.Substring(0, 2), out int hrs) && int.TryParse(time.Substring(2), out int min))
        {
            return new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, hrs, min, 0).ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        // throw exception or return empty;
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G29Jk0)